# how to define personal mutation functions in matlab live scripts

Tags: matlab

I'd like to use a custom mutation function in my live scripts, but I'm having difficulty importing it. It seems that in MATLAB Live Scripts, only built-in mutation functions are supported.

[image]

I've searched both here in mathworks forums but without any luck.
Am I missing something or is it just not supported?

Comment: A Live Script is just a MATLAB script that shows the results of commands inline and can include any MATLAB code you want to write. It looks like you're talking about a Live Editor Task, maybe the [Optimize](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/optimize-live-editor-matlab.html) task? People might be able to help more if you can show a screen shot from an English language version of MATLAB.